# BigQuery - decyphering 'quota exceeded' message

Tags: java, google-bigquery

Im running into this message and Im not clear which of the many quotas Im exceeding. My process has:

- 80 threads (spread over 8 machines)
- < 50 records / insert
- ~5K / record
- 1 sec delay / insert
- inserting into ~100 different tables (depending on the specific record - records for the same table are grouped together)

*To me* this is:

- < max row size (1Mb)
- < max rows / second (100K / table and 1M / project)
- < max rows / request (~500)
- < max bytes / second (100Mb)

Im looking at the output of: `bq --project <proj name> ls -j -a`. This gives me jobs and success/fail. From here I look at the results using `bq --project <proj name> show -j <jobId>`

Error output has these lines:

```
"status": {  
 "errorResult": {  
   "location": "load_job",   
   "message": "Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for imports per project. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors", 
  "reason": "quotaExceeded"  
}, 
"errors": [
  {
    "location": "load_job", 
    "message": "Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for imports per project. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors", 
    "reason": "quotaExceeded"
  }
],
```

Suggestions on where else to look? Am I doing the math wrong? Perhaps a better way to organize the threads / data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [Load Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#import) related

- Daily limit: 1,000 load jobs per table per day (including failures), 10,000 load jobs per project per day (including failures)
- Row and cell size limits:

  ```
  Data format     Max limit   
  CSV             2 MB (row and cell size)  
  JSON            2 MB (row size)  
  Avro            16 MB (block size)
  ```
- Maximum size per load job: 12 TB across all input files for CSV and JSON
- Maximum number of files per load job: 10,000

Most likely `Daily limit` is what you are looking for

Comment: I could see that if the jobs started failing and then *kept failing*. But they don't. Often I'll see several success messages interspersed with the failures. Sometimes quite a few, in fact.

Comment: I can guess that just moving 24 hours is used vs. calendar day, so this could explain what you see. in any case  - you might want to add jobid to your question - so someone from BigQuery team will be able to check what exactly is going on with your job

Comment: Is it secure to post a job id here? Feedback from the BQ team would be divine indeed.

Comment: you can wait for someone from bigquery team to reply/comment on your post, so you will then coordinate with them how to communicate your jobid. usually they are very good at this

Comment: Said that, when I receive 403 error with 'rateLimitExceeded' reason I can see that the job inserted the rows. Now, in a batch load scenario, I don't know if I have to rollback for this error or not and the documentation is not very clear. My default action is to retry and then I have duplications in Bigquery which I'd like to avoid. Any suggestion?

Comment: Were you able to find the quota that was being exceeded? I'm running into the same issue. I'd appreciate If you could provide (and still remember) your fix!

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading data? It seems you are using `jobs.insert` instead of `tabledata.insertAll`.

`jobs.insert` loads data in batch mode. As Mikhail says, the limits of imports per table is 1,000 - that's around one every 90 seconds - if you are using the `jobs.insert` method.

`tabledata.insertAll` allows you to stream data into tables, and here is where the 100k rows per second per table limit applies. Note that this method has a cost associated, while the batch one is free.

Comment: The "API Manager" view reports(over 24 hour span): insertAll - ~24K (62%) insert - ~14K (36%).  Both types of commands are spread over ~50-100 tables so while the 'batch' limit is conceptually being hit these errors were showing up within an hour or two of launching this process.

Comment: I think the 100k rows per second also applies to the whole project(?)

Comment: FYI, new limit: Maximum rows per second: 1,000,000. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas